# Drop all events using single query in mysql 8

Tags: mysql-8.0, mysql-event

Is there any possibilities to drop all events using single query ?
I know, we can get list of events using show events and drop single event with there name.

I also did google for it.but no where showing appopriate solution for it.

Anyone have some idea about it ? It's really appriciated if share some suggestions about it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below query :

```
delete from mysql.event;
```